# Angular html5Mode + ng-include break navigation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include, html5mode

I am trying to use angular with *$locationProvider.html5Mode* enabled and it works fine except when I use *ng-include* somewhere in the page.

```
angular
  .module('AngularApp')
  .config(function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });

<body ng-app="AngularApp">
  <a href="./about.html">internal link breaks</a>
  <ng-include src="'templateId.html'"></ng-include>
</body>
```

Tested on Chrome, Safari and Firefox

You can find a minimum playground of the problem here:
[codepen bug demo](https://codepen.io/samuelmartineau/pen/vWqPrJ?editors=1011)

Any clues?